# Rebuilding LDAP Index on Fedora

Tags: linux, ldap, fedora, openldap

How do you rebuild the LDAP index on Fedora?

I thought the command was slapindex, but I get the error:

```
bdb_db_open: database "dc=mydomain,dc=com": database already in use.
backend_startup_one (type=bdb, suffix="dc=mydomain,dc=com"): bi_db_open failed! (-1)
slap_startup failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before running slapindex you need to stop the LDAP service.  The startup script for LDAP may already run slapindex as part of the startup sequence.  If so, all you need to do is stop and start the LDAP service.

Comment: Would that command be `sudo service slapd restart`?

Comment: @Chris: That is likely the command.  If not you will be notified. I still use `/etc/init.d/slapd restart`.  It should tell you if the startup has been migrated to the newer form.  You can use the `ls -l` command to see if the indexes get rebuilt.  If they don't you will need to stop the service, rebuild the indexes, and then start the service.